# Guess my number game and GUI = stumped :(

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm a beginner, and I'm having a real issue with incorporating a 'Guess my number game' into a GUI. This is a challenge from 'Python programming for the absolute beginner' and there are no solutions contained within the book?!

I can get a single guess and run it through a while loop, but thereafter I'm at a loss. I've spent hours trying various things and have arrived at nothing which works. I'm probably way off track.

I want to be able to get further guesses from the user, but how in a GUI?

Thanks,
Dave (tired and demoralized)

```
My code:

# Guess my number game
# User must attempt to guess randomly selected number within a range in fewest possible attempts

from Tkinter import *
import random

class Application(Frame):
    """A GUI application which which generates random number and gets user input"""

    def __init__(self, master): #initialize newly created Application object
        """Initialize the frame"""
        Frame.__init__(self, master) # super(Application, self).__init__(master) in python 3
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()


    def create_widgets(self):
        """Get user inputs"""
        # create instruction label
        Label(self, text = "I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100.").grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = W)
        Label(self, text = "Try and guess it in as few attempts as possible!").grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = W)

        # create guess input prompt label and entry
        Label(self, text = "Take a guess:").grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = W)
        self.guess_ent = Entry(self)
        self.guess_ent.grid(row = 2, column = 1, sticky = W)

        # create start game prompt label and submit button
        Label(self, text = "Press submit to start the game!").grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = W)
        Button(self, text = "Submit", command = self.run_game).grid(row = 3, column = 1, sticky = W)


        # create submit button
        #Button(self, text = "Submit", command = )

        # create computer feedback text box
        self.text = Text(self, width = 75, height = 10, wrap = WORD)
        self.text.grid(row = 4, column = 0, columnspan = 4)





    def run_game(self):
        """Generate number and get user input"""
        guess = int(self.guess_ent.get())
        number = random.randint(1, 101)

        while guess and guess != number:
            print_text = ""
            print_text += "You guessed "
            print_text += str(guess)
            print_text += "."

            if guess > number:
                print_text += " That's too high. Guess lower..."
            elif guess < number:
                print_text += " That's too low. Guess higher..."

            self.text.delete(0.0, END)
            self.text.insert(0.0, print_text)

            self.guess_ent.delete(0, END)



        #print_text = ""    
        #print_text += "That's the right number! Well done!"
        #self.text.delete(0.0, END)
        #self.text.insert(0.0, print_text)


# main
root = Tk()
root.title("Guess my number game!")
app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Generally speaking, Tkinter apps should not have `while` loops that wait for a widget to change state, because the window will not redraw or respond to user input unless you frequently return control to the mainloop by letting your function end. There's no real "quick fix" here; you need to design your program using a stateful/responsive paradigm rather than the "falling rock" style of console programs.

Comment: Ok. Thanks, that's good to know. I'll ditch the while loop and see what I can come up with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy fix for this. Move `number = random.randint(1, 101)` to the `__init__` function and make it a self variable. Then replace `while` with `if` and your done. Full code looks like this. I made minor changes to `print_text` since 4 lines of code for constructing a string is not necessary. That and changing `number` to `self.number`.

```
# Guess my number game
# User must attempt to guess randomly selected number within a range in fewest possible attempts

from tkinter import *
import random

class Application(Frame):
    """A GUI application which which generates random number and gets user input"""

    def __init__(self, master): #initialize newly created Application object
        """Initialize the frame"""
        Frame.__init__(self, master) # super(Application, self).__init__(master) in python 3
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()
        self.number = random.randint(1, 101)

    def create_widgets(self):
        """Get user inputs"""
        # create instruction label
        Label(self, text = "I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100.").grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = W)
        Label(self, text = "Try and guess it in as few attempts as possible!").grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = W)

        # create guess input prompt label and entry
        Label(self, text = "Take a guess:").grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = W)
        self.guess_ent = Entry(self)
        self.guess_ent.grid(row = 2, column = 1, sticky = W)

        # create start game prompt label and submit button
        Label(self, text = "Press submit to start the game!").grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = W)
        Button(self, text = "Submit", command = self.run_game).grid(row = 3, column = 1, sticky = W)


        # create submit button
        #Button(self, text = "Submit", command = )

        # create computer feedback text box
        self.text = Text(self, width = 75, height = 10, wrap = WORD)
        self.text.grid(row = 4, column = 0, columnspan = 4)

    def run_game(self):
        """Generate number and get user input"""
        guess = int(self.guess_ent.get())

        if guess != self.number:
            print_text = "You guessed {0}.".format(guess)

            if guess > self.number:
                print_text += " That's too high. Guess lower..."
            elif guess < self.number:
                print_text += " That's too low. Guess higher..."

            self.text.delete(0.0, END)
            self.text.insert(0.0, print_text)

            self.guess_ent.delete(0, END)
        else:
            print_text = "That's the right number! Well done!"
            self.text.delete(0.0, END)
            self.text.insert(0.0, print_text)

# main
root = Tk()
root.title("Guess my number game!")
app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Haha! I did, at one point, use self.number in the constructor, but with the while loop still there. Thankyou very much!